# Form switching in c# vs Without the event form_load to kick in

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best way of switching between 3 or more forms? (Without having to load the form every time you switch)

Comment: Your question is unclear. The form_load does not fire when switching back and forth between forms. Can you explain in a little more detail what is happening and show an example of the code that is causing this?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[formName].Activate()`

Comment: isnt it enough to just toggle visibility of the forms?, you need a reference to all three in your main code so your application doesnt forget about them

Comment: @CharlesMay I am working on a benchmarking app that has 4 forms, each with lots of background process and my issue is that after switching forms it uses more and more resources and i have no clue how to optimize this. Here is the switching:                                                                                          
  private void CPU_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CpuForm tempcpu = new CpuForm();
            tempcpu.Show();
            tempcpu.Top = this.Top;
            tempcpu.Left = this.Left;
            this.Hide();//*
        }

Comment: This is the switch back (couldn t add in in the last comment since it was too long):                                                                                   
     private void HomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainScreen temp1 = new MainScreen();
            temp1.Show();
            temp1.Top = this.Top;
            temp1.Left = this.Left;
            this.Hide();//*
        }

Comment: If you are constructing new instances of the form types and then showing these instances there is no proper way to avoid this. Instead, keep the old instances and re-show them when needed, hide them when not needed. Since you construct new forms but hide the existing ones, you're leaking forms as you keep them in memory in a hidden state.

Comment: You're using resources because you're hiding each form and creating a new one every time. You can use @stuartd's example, only instead of activate, set the visible property to true. Or Bacon's example of keeping track of the forms and setting their visibility as needed.

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

As Bacon mentioned in his comment, you have to keep references for each form. As soon as you need one of them you call it (change visibility or some other method which fits good for your case). What I asume in your case is that you are creating new form everytime instead of calling the old one. This is why you are using more and more resources everytime you click a form.